# Twig loop. control class names

Tags: php, html, css, twig

Im trying in Twig to set different classes depending on how may items that gets rendered. Eg, if only one, if only two, if only three etc I want to set a different class on the

item. How would I do that?

```
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
        <li>
            {% include 'components/list/person.twig' with item %}
        </li>       
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't you set an attribute 'css_class` inside your `item object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know in advice the length of the loop, you can use the predefined [loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) that is named length:

> loop.length: The number of items in the sequence

as example:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ loop.index }}/{{ loop.length }} - {{ user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

hope this help

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that i understood your question or not...

But if you want to use different classes on base of index of loop then you can use `loop.index` in loop.

Hope this will help you

```
<ul>
  {% for item in items %}
    {℅ if loop.index == 1  ℅}
        // Set class here
    {℅ endif %}
      <li>
          {% include 'components/list/person.twig' with item %}
      </li>       
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```